# How to use Bootstrap tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to understand how to do this: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

I think the documentation is not detailed enough, because I can not understand how it works.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav active"><a href="#A" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#B" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#C" data-toggle="tab">C</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="A">Content inside tab A</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="B">Content inside tab B</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="C">Content inside tab C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code gives me what I want
[image]

However I can't switch between tabs.

So the question is: what JQuery or Javascript code should I add to make it work? What is shown in the example does not work :(

Comment: did you include jquery and bootstrap js files

Comment: I agree with you that Bootstrap's documentation is too elliptical - they leave things in out in many of their examples.

Comment: you also have ids problem, you put href="#B" but your second tab id is not "B" but "MySQL". Same thing with third tab

Comment: That is not the issue. I just copied wrong piese of code here. I have edited initial post. Now there is correct IDs. However it didn't help

Comment: well if you added js files properly you should have no problems, bootstrap js handles tab switching

Comment: Nope, I need a piece of JS or Jquery code..something like event handler?

Comment: If you are looking for more detailed examples, you _might_ find the following helpful: http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.2.0/docs/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This code works:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav active"><a href="#A" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#B" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#C" data-toggle="tab">C</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="A">Content inside tab A</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="B">Content inside tab B</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="C">Content inside tab C</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.intellisense.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>

So what the difference?

Comment: Check your path, it is maybe wrong : "../Scripts/" ?

Comment: I use Visual Studio. Scripts - is the folder that was created automatically when I have installed NUGet Package (like bootstrap and JQuery) then I just drag n drop a script file from that folder to my document, and VS generates the link automatically.

Comment: '    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.intellisense.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>'
tabs doesn't work. (I add this in the head section)

Comment: @AndreyLangovoy use the backtick " ` " to designate code blocks in comments. :-)

Answer (score 13):

If you want to use simple tabs without Dropdown you can use this easy method

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type='text/css'>
        body {
        padding: 20px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.5;
        font-size: 14px;
        }
        .tabs-menu {
        height: 30px;
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        }
        .tabs-menu li {
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
        border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
        border-left: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
        }
        .tabs-menu li.current {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
        z-index: 5;
        }
        .tabs-menu li a {
        padding: 10px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        }
        .tabs-menu .current a {
        color: #2e7da3;
        }
        .tab {
        border: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
        background-color: #fff;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width: auto;
        }
        .tab-content {
        width: 660px;
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        }
        #tab-1 {
        display: block;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tabs-container">
            <ul class="tabs-menu">
                <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab">
                <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sit amet purus urna. Proin dictum fringilla enim, sit amet suscipit dolor dictum in. Maecenas porttitor, est et malesuada congue, ligula elit fermentum massa, sit amet porta odio est at velit. Sed nec turpis neque. Fusce at mi felis, sed interdum tortor. Nullam pretium, est at congue mattis, nibh eros pharetra lectus, nec posuere libero dui consectetur arcu. Quisque convallis facilisis fermentum. Nam tincidunt, diam nec dictum mattis, nunc dolor ultrices ipsum, in mattis justo turpis nec ligula. Curabitur a ante mauris. Integer placerat imperdiet diam, facilisis pretium elit mollis pretium. Sed lobortis, eros non egestas suscipit, dui dui euismod enim, ac ultricies arcu risus at tellus. Donec imperdiet congue ligula, quis vulputate mauris ultrices non. Aliquam rhoncus, arcu a bibendum congue, augue risus tincidunt massa, vel vehicula diam dolor eget felis.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
                    <p>Donec semper dictum sem, quis pretium sem malesuada non. Proin venenatis orci vel nisl porta sollicitudin. Pellentesque sit amet massa et orci malesuada facilisis vel vel lectus. Etiam tristique volutpat auctor. Morbi nec massa eget sem ultricies fermentum id ut ligula. Praesent aliquet adipiscing dictum. Suspendisse dignissim dui tortor. Integer faucibus interdum justo, mattis commodo elit tempor id. Quisque ut orci orci, sit amet mattis nulla. Suspendisse quam diam, feugiat at ullamcorper eget, sagittis sed eros. Proin tortor tellus, pulvinar at imperdiet in, egestas sed nisl. Aenean tempor neque ut felis dignissim ac congue felis viverra. </p>
                </div>
                <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
                    <p>Duis egestas fermentum ipsum et commodo. Proin bibendum consectetur elit, hendrerit porta mi dictum eu. Vestibulum adipiscing euismod laoreet. Vivamus lobortis tortor a odio consectetur pulvinar. Proin blandit ornare eros dictum fermentum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur laoreet, ante aliquet molestie laoreet, lectus odio fringilla purus, id porttitor erat velit vitae mi. Nullam posuere nunc ut justo sollicitudin interdum. Donec suscipit eros nec leo condimentum fermentum. Nunc quis libero massa. Integer tempus laoreet lectus id interdum. Integer facilisis egestas dui at convallis. Praesent elementum nisl et erat iaculis a blandit ligula mollis. Vestibulum vitae risus dui, nec sagittis arcu. Nullam tortor enim, placerat quis eleifend in, viverra ac lacus. Ut aliquam sapien ut metus hendrerit auctor dapibus justo porta. </p>
                </div>
                <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
                    <p>Proin sollicitudin tincidunt quam, in egestas dui tincidunt non. Maecenas tempus condimentum mi, sed convallis tortor iaculis eu. Cras dui dui, tempor quis tempor vitae, ullamcorper in justo. Integer et lorem diam. Quisque consequat lectus eget urna molestie pharetra. Cras risus lectus, lobortis sit amet imperdiet sit amet, eleifend a erat. Suspendisse vel luctus lectus. Sed ac arcu nisi, sit amet ornare tellus. Pellentesque nec augue a nibh pharetra scelerisque quis sit amet felis. Nullam at enim at lacus pretium iaculis sit amet vel nunc. Praesent sapien felis, tincidunt vitae blandit ut, mattis at diam. Suspendisse ac sapien eget eros venenatis tempor quis id odio. Donec lacus leo, tincidunt eget molestie at, pharetra cursus odio. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().addClass("current");
                $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
                var tab = $(this).attr("href");
                $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
                $(tab).fadeIn();
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syahrasi/us8uc/)

Get some best tab Demos [Here](http://w2ui.com/web/demos/#!tabs/tabs-1)

Thank you.
Seecoding Team

Comment: @DjDac Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="YOUR_WEBSITE_ROOT/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Js files available here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download

Answer (score 0):

*(Note:  rewrote answer to just be one main answer.)*

**INCLUDE THE NECESSARY BOOTSTRAP CSS/JS FILES!**
Make sure you **include all necessary Bootstrap CSS (**`<link>`**) and JS (**`<script>`**) files!**  They can be found in the ["Getting Started > Introduction" section of Bootstrap's website.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/)

***NOTE:**  Also, if you want your displayed HTML content to change based on what tab is active, the code samples closer to the bottom of [Bootstrap's Tabs page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navs-tabs/) (currently underneath the header "Javascript Behavior”) have the necessary attributes and additional HTML tags to make that happen.  The code samples on the top and middle of the page are examples of the tabs only.*

**Code example including necessary Bootstrap CSS/JS files & Bootstrap sample code that includes the changing content panes:** (click 'Run code snippet')

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS file (usually within header) -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Bootstrap code sample with changing content panes (“tab content”) -->
<!-- tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- tab content -->
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap JS file (usually before </body>) -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```