# Bootstrap tabs in layout.cshtml - not rendering body

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have just started learning mvc with bootstrap. I have setup a layout page like the following:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("HomE", "Index", "Home", null, new { @data_toggle = "tab", Href = "#Home" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("ProgramminG", "Programming", "Home", null, new { @data_toggle = "tab", Href = "#Programming" })</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
```

My HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }
public ActionResult Programming()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your Programming tab page";

        return View();
    }
```

My Views:
Index.cshtml

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div id="Home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>This is from home view's index.cshtml.</p>
</div>
```

Programming.cshtml

```
    @{    
    ViewBag.Title = "Programming";    
}
    <div id="Programming" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Programming</h3>
        <p>This is from home view's Programming.cshtml</p>
    </div>
```

The problem I am having is that when the nav bar shows up, I click home and it displays home or index's content in renderbody just fine.
However when I click on programming, renderbody doesn't change at all.

Could someone help with this please?

Comment: Why does Programming div need tab-pane fade classes?

Comment: Did you put breakpoint on Programming action to see if action fire truly?

Comment: @artm. I was following an example from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667368/how-to-use-bootstrap-tabs. That worked for me so then I modified that by putting the tabs in a layout page and using renderbody hoping to show the content of each tab via separate actions/cshtml

Comment: @Siamak. I just tested and it didn't fire. However when I manually changed the address to localhost:12345/Home/Programming it fired. Do I need to modify the route or something similar?

Comment: It looks be true! Test it by changing the name of Programming in both ActionLink and Action name and remove class defination from ActionLink...

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, Siamak. It worked. I removed the class from cshtml and modified the actionlink to be just "@Html.ActionLink("ProgramminG", "Programming", "Home")".
Also thank you, artm. I just found out that the class wasn't needed at all in the div.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the pointers, Siamak and artm.

The following modifications fixed the issue:
Modified actionlink

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("HomE", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("ProgramminG", "Programming", "Home")</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Removed class from div in views

```
     @{    
    ViewBag.Title = "Programming";    
}
    <div id="Programming">
        <h3>Programming</h3>
        <p>This is from home view's Programming.cshtml</p>
    </div>
```